# Solve $\cot x \csc x + \cot x = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cot x \csc x + \cot x = 0$$

Give exact answers in radians.

I tried $$\cot x(\csc x +1)=0$$
$$\cot x =0, \csc x= -1$$
But I'm not sure if that is correct. Please show me how to do this problem. I wanna learn!

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify on what cot x csc =-1 means. Do you mean $$\cot x \csc x =-1$$Or $$\cot x=0, \csc x=-1$$?

Comment: Yes I meant the second one. Could you please show me the steps of solving this question? I don't know the answer as well.

Comment: $\cot x = {\cos x \over \sin x}$, so $\cot x = 0$ implies that $\cos x = 0$. Similarly, $\csc x = {1\over \sin x}$, so you know that you could also have $\sin x = {1\over -1} = -1$.

Comment: Could you please show me step by step? I'm still confused. So what I got is correct? i dont even understand what I did.

Comment: @MaryZ Would you mind terribly if I told you the answer? And I think you are just using $$a(b+c)=ab+ac$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$
\cot x \csc x + \cot x \;\; =\;\; \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \frac{1}{\sin x} + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \;\; =\;\; 0
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x} \;\; =\;\; - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}.
$$

Cross-multiplying we find that

$$
\frac{1}{\sin x} \;\; =\;\; -1
$$

or rather $\sin x = -1$.  This should be simple now.  Observe additionally that this also occurs when $\cos x = 0$ which should be simple as well.

Comment: So would the answer be 1/2(2πn+π),1/2(4πn−π),1/2(4πn+3π)?

Comment: @MaryZ It's hard for me to read your answer, I'd recommend learning how to typeset your questions/answers [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  I think you have the right idea, but your solutions don't seem totally correct.

Comment: Could you proceed on solving the question? Thank you so much for your help.